# HTACCESS file extention removed, but can't access index file because of directory and file conflicts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Having problems finding a solution to this...

I have removed all file extensions from the url with the following .htaccess script.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But when I try to access a directory it throws me to our standard 404 page.

For Example:

www.website.com/directory-name/page-name (works)

www.website.com/directory-name (does not go to index or directory-name.php) even though they both exist.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude existent dirs from the RewriteRule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi Starkeen, as my htaccess is poor I am experiencing another small problem.... whenever my href directs to a directory, it is removing my https protocol, for example my link https://www.website.com/page will work but  https://www.website.com/directory/ will rewrite as work but  www.website.com/directory/ (excluding the https) any ideas?

Comment: @peter can you ask a new question please?